# Unable to parse date from curl output

Tags: php, date, curl

I am currently having issues when I try to parse a date. Basically, I am trying to parse the data from a curl output.

Here's my curl function :

```
function curlFunction(){
        $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/querydate.php" );
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
            if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
                echo "Connection Error : Please Try Again!";
            } else {
                $h_output = $output;
            }
              curl_close($ch);

        return $h_output;

}
```

Here's the output from the curl function:

```
May 23, 2017
```

Here's how I declare it from my code :

```
$curlOutput = curlFunction();
```

Here's my PHP code for parsing :

```
var_dump(date_parse_from_format('F j, Y', $curlOutput) );
```

Here's the output :

```
array(12) { ["year"]=> int(2017) ["month"]=> bool(false) ["day"]=> int(23) ["hour"]=> bool(false) ["minute"]=> bool(false) ["second"]=> bool(false) ["fraction"]=> bool(false) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) ["warnings"]=> array(0) { } ["error_count"]=> int(3) ["errors"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(22) "Unexpected data found." [32]=> string(13) "Trailing data" } ["is_localtime"]=> bool(false) }
```

Year and the Day are getting parsed except for the month.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. A more simplified version is:

```
$curlOutput = 'May 23, 2017';

print_r(date_parse_from_format('F j, Y', $curlOutput) );
```

And this returns:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2017
    [month] => 5
    [day] => 23
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

I can correctly see the year, month and day in the response.

Comment: Yes, the code is working, that is if it is not being parsed from the curl function. When I run the curl function, and then parse the output, it fails.

Comment: There must be some other problem with the code. Can you add more of your code to the question and then we can see if we can replicate the issue

Comment: I have edited it now. I have added the function part.

Comment: Have a go trimming the output before you return it, e.g. `return trim($h_output);`

Comment: When i do echo $curlOutput, it shows May 23, 2017. But parsing still fails. I have already added trim.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does Trailing data error tells ?

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so hard?
Use strtotime and use date to "parse" it.

```
$d ="May 23, 2017";
Echo strtotime($d) ."<br>\n";
Echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($d));
```

https://3v4l.org/qSEID